# Why Bootstrap.js not loaded in my Laravel's Vite config?

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vite

In my Laravel 10 *vite.config.js* I try to load Bootstrap.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";

import { readdirSync,lstatSync } from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';


function getFilesFromDir(dir, fileTypes) {
    const filesToReturn = [];

    function walkDir(currentPath) {

        if(lstatSync(currentPath).isFile()){
            filesToReturn.push(currentPath);
            return;
        }

        const files = readdirSync(currentPath);
        for (let i in files) {
            console.log(files[i]);
            const curFile = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            if(lstatSync(curFile).isDirectory()){
                walkDir(curFile);
                continue;
            }
            const file = resolve(dir, files[i]);
            filesToReturn.push(file);
        }
    }

    walkDir(resolve(__dirname, dir));
    return filesToReturn;
}


// Get all .css and .scss files in the directory
const pageStyles = getFilesFromDir('./resources/css', ['css', 'scss']);
const js = getFilesFromDir('./resources/js',['js']);

const paths = [

    ...pageStyles,
    ...js,

    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
    'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
]

console.log(paths);

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input:paths,
            refresh: true,
        }),
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'common_functions':'resources/js/common_functions.js',
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                "js/modules/*",
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

And I have installed Bootstrap in my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "build_dev": "vite build --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rollup/plugin-inject": "^5.0.5",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "emodal": "^1.2.69",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "nodejs": "^0.0.0",
        "scss": "^0.2.4"
    }
}
```

But Once I do:

```
    @vite(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'])
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.
```

Despite that file does exist and be in vite.config.js:

```
$ ls -l  node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 207731 Jan  5 08:30 node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js
```

```
l$ grep "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" vite.config.js
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
```

What can I try to resolve this?